# Create DataFrame with multiple arrays by column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating a DataFrame with pandas. The source is from multiple arrays, but I want to create DataFrames column by column, not row by row in default pandas.Dataframe() function.

[image]

pd.DataFrame seems to have lack of 'axis=' parameter, how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: 1. please add your picture as text, don't expect others to write out your [mcve] 2. please add an expected output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use python's built-in `zip` for that following way:

```
import pandas as pd
arrayA = ['f','d','g']
arrayB = ['1','2','3']
arrayC = [4,5,6]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(arrayA, arrayB, arrayC), columns=['AA','NN','gg'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  AA NN  gg
0  f  1   4
1  d  2   5
2  g  3   6
```

Comment: zip is better here.

Comment: Thank you guys! It's really handy and useful !

Answer (score 1):

Zip is a great solution in this case as pointed out by Daweo, but alternatively you can use a dictionary for readability purposes:

```
import pandas as pd

arrayA = ['f','d','g']
arrayB = ['1','2','3']
arrayC = [4,5,6]

my_dict = {
    'AA': arrayA,
    'NN': arrayB,
    'gg': arrayC
}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df)
```

Output

```
    AA  NN  gg
0   f   1   4
1   d   2   5
2   g   3   6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll memo this.